# Modify a 2D array using passing by reference in C

Tags: c, arrays, function, arguments

I've been working on a simple C checkers game.

I want the function *cargar_partida* (load game) to read a text file which contains a list of numbers (64 in total) that represent every position in the game.

1 represents a blank space that can be occupied, 0 a blank space that can't be occupied, 2 the white pieces and 3 the black ones.
FIL and COL value is 8.

Here's the function:

```
int cargar_partida(int *turno, int *tablanueva[FIL][COL]) {

int i, j;
FILE * archivo;

archivo = fopen("partida.txt", "r");

if (archivo == NULL) {
    printf("Error al abrir el archivo.\n");
    exit(0);
}

fscanf(archivo, "%d", turno);

for (i = 0; i < FIL; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < COL; j++) {
        fscanf(archivo, "%d", tablanueva[i][j]);
    }

}
}
```

The variable *turno* (turn in english) is loaded correctly, but the 2D array *tablanueva* (new array) isn't.

NOTE: In the file *partida.txt* the variable *turno* is the first one to apear, the other values apear each one in a different row.

This is the initial array, which has to be changed when *cargar_partida* is called. The problem is that the function doesn't change it. The array's declaration is located in the main function.

```
int tabla[FIL][COL] = {
    {0, N, 0, N, 0, N, 0, N},
    {N, 0, N, 0, N, 0, N, 0},
    {0, N, 0, N, 0, N, 0, N},
    {VAL, 0, VAL, 0, VAL, 0, VAL, 0},
    {0, VAL, 0, VAL, 0, VAL, 0, VAL},
    {B, 0, B, 0, B, 0, B, 0},
    {0, B, 0, B, 0, B, 0, B},
    {B, 0, B, 0, B, 0, B, 0},
  };
```

This is how the function is called.

```
cargar_partida(&opcion, tabla);
```

Comment: How is the 2D array declared in main?

Comment: @matts It's the second block of code (not sure if you mean that)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing a double pointer `(tabla)` as a parameter in

```
cargar_partida(&opcion, tabla);
```

The function expects a pointer to a 2D array (a triple pointer). Thus, you have to change the type of the second parameter in your function.

This should work

```
int cargar_partida(int *turno, int tablanueva[FIL][COL])
```

if it does not work, let us know.

Comment: it also needs `fscanf(archivo, "%d", &tablanueva[i][j]);`, notice the `&`.

Comment: Just tried what @matts said and using the &. Now the compiler doesn't give me any warning, but the values aren't correctly changed and it always print the same initial array instead of the one that I saved in the txt file.

Comment: @101010 How I read all of them then? I thought the double for bucle was doing it (?)